# Python script not running when added to crontab

Tags: pi-3, python, cron, python-3

I have an `on_reboot.sh` file that contains the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

source /home/pi/.profile
workon cv
cd /home/pi/reboot
python pi_test.py
```

After that I made the file executable using

```
$ chmod +x on_reboot.sh
```

and then in my crontab I put the following to run it on boot:

```
@reboot /home/pi/reboot/on_reboot.sh
```

However, it is not working when the Pi boots up. When I run the sh file on the command line it is working fine. I tried modifying the crontab like this:

```
@reboot sudo su – pi bash -c ‘/home/pi/reboot/on_reboot.sh’
```

to run the startup script as user pi but is not working either. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should start your script as service with a *systemd* unit. It seems the script only runs one time and does not stay in the background. I don't know other edge conditions of your script but with this what I see I would define a unit file with:

```
rpi ~$ sudo systemctl edit --force on_reboot.service
```

In the empty editor insert these statements, save them and quit the editor:

```
[Unit]
Description=Script On Reboot

[Service]
User=pi
WorkingDirectory=/home/pi
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/home/pi/reboot/on_reboot.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Edit again with `sudo systemctl edit --full on_reboot.service`.

Enable the service:

```
rpi ~$ sudo systemctl enable on_reboot.service
```

Reboot.

Check with `systemctl status on_reboot.service`

Comment: sir the script runs on reboot, but after 1 to 2 seconds it became off the script is not running anymore

Comment: this is the error when i check it https://pastebin.com/xJ2nE4iP

Comment: Yes, that's because the script do things I don't know. It will connect to a server. What server? What connection? Python will output something. What output? Seems it is a graphical output.

Comment: Already fix sir im using opencv.imshow which shows the video stream on screen i jst disable it and everything works fine now thanks sir